# Is it possible to place doors in existing structures?

Tags: fallout-4

I deleted a pre existing door on a house to replace with a different one and it won't let me. No matter how I try to place it, it stays in the red. Can you not swap out doors?

Comment: In the one place I've bothered to work around this so far (PC's own house, carport door), I just added a new doorway close enough to the house that the gap wouldn't matter much, then put a door in that. Extremely crude, perhaps, but effective.

Comment: A point of trivia that I found from watching a Fallout 4 video on Youtube: The Red Rocket actually has sliding pocket doors in all of it's doorways.  No need to place new doors at this base location.

Comment: It's possible to [place in red](http://www.nexusmods.com/fallout4/mods/1267/?) (a mod that requires Cheat Engine) almost anything.

Answer (score 7):

It looks like you can, but it's a little difficult at this time. Here's a video I found on the [Fallout4 subreddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/fo4/), explaining how to place doors in pre-war houses, not sure though if it works with player built houses:

Comment: mind = blown...

Comment: Pretty sad it's so complicated, hopefully bethesda will patch that soon.

Answer (score 1):

Um,  a much quicker fix for you guys....

I know this is old, but to anyone wanting to add a door to an existing structure, just go align yourself in the empty doorway, walk through it until you can't quite see the frame. Keep your face looking straight and make sure the door frame is in line with you, and just behind you.

Go to console,  type `"help door 0"` into the console, scroll to find a door code you want (under DOOR only!) 
And then type:

```
player.placeatme xxxxxx 1
```

with x being the door number. The door will spawn EXACTLY where you stand. So get used to your angle and distance from door frame. It's easy once you do your first one. Then just rinse and repeat, and save a new save.

Done ALL my doors in Covenant in about 15 minutes, and they function perfectly.